# How to wrap UserDefinedType* getObject() and populate Java container from a member of type const uint16_t* of the returned object

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have the following `struct` which contains a data member `pixeldata_` which is a pointer to an array of short ints. Size of this array is width * height.

```
struct Frame
{
public:
    const uint16_t* getPixelData()
    {
        return this->pixeldata_;
    }
    int getWidth() { return this->width_; }
    int getHeight(){ return this->height_; }
    void setPixelData(const uint16_t* pixeldata)
    {
        this->pixeldata_ = pixeldata;
    }
    int getSize(){ return this->width_*this->height_; }
private:
    const uint16_t* pixeldata_{nullptr};
    int width_ {0}; // typically 640 for our use case
    int height_{0}; // typically 480 for our use case
};
```

Using `%include "stdint.i"` creates an opaque pointer of type `SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_short` which I cannot dereference. How can I copy that array into a Java container favorably an ArrayList of `unsigned short`

So, how would I wrap the following code for Java and access the member `pixeldata_` and retrieve the array of short ints from C++ layer to Java containers?

```
Frame* Sensor::getFrame();
Frame* frame = getFrame();
auto pixel_data = frame->getPixelData();
for (auto pixel : pixel_data)
{
// possibly create an image or texture 
}
```